# How do I know when quiche is finished cooking?

Tags: baking, eggs, quiche

Whenever I've cooked quiche, it's been in a round tin of around 10-12 cm diameter. I've used 5-6 eggs along with other ingredients like chicken and vegetables.

After it comes out of the oven, I find that the height is low (around 2cm) when I thought/expected it to be higher.

I find it hard to know when it's actually 'cooked' as the egg parts are runny when it's in the oven, only solidifying when I take it out.

How can I tell that the quiche is done?

Comment: I read this over several times and I don't actually see a question.

Comment: There is nothing that would make a quiche rise, 2 cm is pretty normal. The quiche should solidify in the oven... What exactly are you asking here? (FWIW, I bake mine for 35 minutes and I never had issues.)

Comment: Quiche can rise if you introduce air bubbles when you mix the eggs, as the bubbles grow. However it's not generally considered desirable.

Comment: FYI: *most* quiches should cook for 30-50 minutes. I arrived at this page a few hours ago because the recipe I was following said to cook it for 15 min. That gave me aromatic, eggy soup. :-)

Answer (score 10):

Inferring that the question is, "How do I tell when the quiche is done?" The answer is to check the [internal temperature](http://www.preparedpantry.com/Make-your-own-quiche.htm), which should be between 165°F(74°C) and 185°F(85°C).

Comment: That's a bit of a problem with my oven, as I have a portable temperature gauge inside, which says it's several degrees lower than the knob is at. (marked in 10 degree increments by dots, with 120 and 200 marked)

Comment: not the oven temperature, but the internal temperature of the quiche itself. [Use an 'instant read' thermometer like this](http://www.amazon.com/CDN-DTQ450X-ProAccurate-Quick-Read-Thermometer/dp/B0021AEAG2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1363251139&sr=8-1&keywords=instant+read+thermometer) to see what the temperature of the quiche is.

Answer (score 7):

Stick a knife directly in the center from above and when it comes out clean ( no uncooked egg mixture, very small amount of oil or clear liquid ok) it's done. Also 165-185F internal temp also measured directly in the center.